# How to use same variable or query result in all the page in laravel

Tags: laravel-5

am using laravel 5.4, I want to use some query for all the page.
Like I have one table to set permission for users. If users have permission then they will be able to get some extra menu. I have created a new page '_menu.blade.php'. This page is included to the all page. So, now what happening is, I have to check for all pages controller for users permission table and send those data. 
Suppose, I have `home.blade.php`. Here I have added `menu.blade.php` and then my controller for `home.blade.php` is

```
public function index(){
 $Permission  = Permission::where('edit',$currentUserId)->first();
return view('home')->withPermission($Permission);
}
```

And also I have `read.blade.php`. Here also I have added `menu.blade.php` and then my controller for `read.blade.php` is

```
public function index(){
 $Permission  = Permission::where('edit',$currentUserId)->first();
return view('read')->withPermission($Permission);
}
```

Here I have to fetch users permission for all the pages. Now What I want is, Just fetch user `permission` at once and use this `permission` in all the pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [share data with all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) using:

```
public function boot()
{
    $Permission = Permission::where('edit',$currentUserId)->first();

    View::share('Permission', $Permission);
}
```

Add this to your `AppServiceProvider`.